# Selecting entire variable with double click

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm, when you double click on a variable, say `$_helloWorld`, it just selects a part of the variable. For example, when you double click on `World` and it will select just that instead of the entire variable.

I want it to select the entire variable `$_helloWorld` when I double click on any part of it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 26):

For me, PhpStorm on Linux will only select entire variables on double click if I have the option:

> File | Settings | Editor | General
>
> Honor "CamelHumps" word settings when selecting using double click

turned off. See [documentation here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/general.html).

Answer (score 24):

Super late answer, haha, but here is the exact option to enable selecting `$` in variable names:

> File | Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Select variable name without '$' sign on double click

Should be `disabled`.

Comment: Never mid the late answer, turned out useful another 3 years later.

Answer (score 8):

For Rider it's under

```
File > Settings > Editor > General > Typing Assistance
```

and then at the bottom the last checkbox:

```
Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click
```

should be turned off.

Answer (score 5):

Please enable this option:
File | Settings | IDE settings | Editor | Smart keys | Use "CamelHumps" words.

And check if this one enabled:
File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor | Honor "CamelHumps" word settings when selecting using double click.

Comment: Yes both are selected, and BTW I am on Mac OS X 10 (in case if that makes any difference)

Comment: It's worth noting the same problem and solution applies for Rider.

Answer (score 2):

Using WebStorm on Windows 8.1 I was able to fix this by going to

```
File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Editor
```

and disabling the following option:

```
Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click
```

Answer (score 0):

For the folks who are using Mac, this is what you got to do:

### **Step 1:** Select preferences option in PhpStorm Menu

[image: preferences menu option]

### **Step 2:** Once the window appears get the Smart Keys settings like so, which will be inside the following menu

> Editor > General > Smart Keys

[image: Smart Keys Settings]

### **Step 3:** Uncheck the checkbox next to `Honor "CamelHumps" words settings when selecting on double click`

[image: smart keys option]