# Not select dollar ($) in PhpStorm on double-click?

Tags: variables, ide, format, settings, phpstorm

I am coming from Dreamweaver into PhpStorm 8.0.2 (on Windows 8.1).

How do you set it up so that when selecting a variable, you do not select the dollar ($)? This needs to include variables separated by underscores.

I have tried the various settings to do with CamelHumps, and had mixed results, but still not ideal.

For example, double-clicking the variable `$foo_bar`, I would like it to select `foo_bar`.

- With "Honor CamelHumps", it will select `$foo_bar`.
- Without "Honor CamelHumps", it will select `foo` or `bar` depending on which word you double-click on.

Comment: What language? If PHP then there is no such option -- `$` always gets selected.

Comment: Thanks - hopefully they release this option in a future version.

Answer (score 16):

File | Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | PHP -> `Select variable name without '$' sign on double click`

Comment: Thanks a millon. Worked for me.

Comment: Apparently, the option does not work for shell scripts like Bash, and double-clicking on `$foobar` even with the option enabled, the whole variable gets selected including the `$-dollar` sign.

Answer (score 5):

It's now fixed - there is an option to allow selecting of `$` in variable names - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42624161/4879058

Answer (score 0):

you should click exactly underscore sign when double clicking to select foo_bar

Comment: And how to **not** select dollar sign (`$`) when you are using _camelCase_ and your variable names _does not_ contain underscore?